# Combining multiple rows inside the ELSE of a CASE expression

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN inputNumber != 0 THEN  inputNumber 
             ELSE  111             
        END as Column_Name
FROM dual
```

Hi all, `inputNumber` is the input , based on that I have to create output , if its  0 then , my result should contain three rows with 111, 222, 333

Above query is working but I want to add 222, 333 also in the Else part , please suggest so that in result it will be total 3 rows where input is  equals to 0

So now , if the input is 0 then output is

```
Column_Name
  111
```

I want to make it as

```
Column_Name
  111
  222
  333
```

Comment: What is the bigger context of this?  Where are you using this function?  Is this really selecting from `dual` or will it be selecting from a table?  Note that one invocation returns one row normally.  You can put a loop around it or use `union` - but you can't simply return 3 values where 1 is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly, but should work:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN inputNumber != 0 THEN  inputNumber 
             ELSE  111             
        END as Column_Name
FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 222 
FROM dual 
WHERE inputNumber = 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 333
FROM dual 
WHERE inputNumber = 0
```

**Update:**

Maybe more readable:

```
SELECT  inputNumber  as Column_Name
FROM dual
WHERE inputNumber != 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 111
FROM dual 
WHERE inputNumber = 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 222 
FROM dual 
WHERE inputNumber = 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 333
FROM dual 
WHERE inputNumber = 0
```

PS: Sorry, I didn't test this...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN :inputnumber = 0 THEN 111 * LEVEL ELSE :inputnumber END column_name
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CASE WHEN :inputnumber = 0 THEN 3 ELSE 1 END;
```

With :inputnumber = 0:

```
COLUMN_NAME
-----------
        111
        222
        333
```

With :inputnumber = 1:

```
COLUMN_NAME
-----------
          1
```